# Uncaught TypeError: .filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have read https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_filter. But I don't know why function doesn't work.

```
var bubble = d3.pack()
    .size([diameter, diameter])
    .padding(2);

var root = d3.hierarchy({"children": data.values});

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(bubble(root)
        .filter(function(d) {return !d.children;}))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
```

Comment: Please, paste your `bubble` function.

Comment: pasted @GerardoFurtado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can pass your data to the `pack()`  function, you have to pass it to `d3.hierarchy()`, which:

> Constructs a root node from the specified hierarchical data.

So, given your data object:

```
var data = {
    //Hierarchical data here
};
```

You have to pass it to `d3.hierarchy()`:

```
var root = d3.hierarchy(data);
```

Then, you can use `bubble`:

```
.data(bubble(root))
```

EDIT: Since you changed the *title* of your question, the problem is now clear: `bubble(root)` returns an **object**, and you cannot use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in an object. That's an **array** method.

Comment: Look at the changes, please

Comment: @ДастанКойшыбаев Now the problem is clear: `bubble(root)` returns an **object**. You cannot use `filter` in an object, filter is an **array** method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I used `Array.prototype.slice.call(bubble(root))` and problem disappeared, but appeared a new(. _Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null_ . Have you any idea? Sorry for my importunity

Comment: _property is used on a node that is itself a document, the result is null_ - found it. But with v3 code works correctly @GerardoFurtado

Comment: At this point it's impossible to help you without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, I suggest you to post a new question, since this question has changed so many times.